# Custom Piechart Symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, symbology, arcgis-pro, chart

I am using ArcGIS Pro to draw Pie chart from two columns.
Actual Budget vs Planned Budget
It is working like normal pie chart that is if we have 60 in **actual budget** and 100 in **planned budget**. It will calculate percentage of **actual budget** with the sum of **actual budget and planned budget**. This percentage will be depicted in Pie chart. so in this example it will be 60/(100+60) = 37.5%

This is the normal working of pie chart even if we draw it in excel. What i want is instead of creating a chart like this i want to show **actual budget** percentage. So in the above example instead of getting 37.5% i want to get 60/100 = 60%. And i want my pie chart in ArcGIS Pro symbology to show me 60% area covered.

Comment: As far as I know, by default, this cannot be achieved through the symbology in ArcGIS Pro, but what you can do is add a new field, calculate the field according to your formula, and set the symbology for that field.